# Restrict direct folder access via .htaccess except via specific links

Tags: apache, htaccess

I want to restrict access to a folder on my server so that visitors may only access the contents (a web application) via links in the same domain.  Can I do this using .htaccess? To be clear, I simply want to prevent direct access to the contents so that visitors are routed through other pages on my website in order to get there.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this might work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([-a-z0-9]+\.)?YOURDOMAIN\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/PROTECTEDFOLDER/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.YOURDOMAIN\.com\/$1" [R=301]
```

I'm haven't tried this, but it should work. Some explanation:

- If the referrer is not from your domain, or a subdomain...
- If the folder "PROTECTEDFOLDER" is being accessed...
- Redirect to your homepage.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that the `HTTP_REFERER` is dependent on the clients browser, so is inherently unreliable and can be faked. So you could find that legitimate users are unable to access your app and 3rd party sites can access your app anyway. This might only affect a small percentage, but it's something to be aware of.